# Sort by price daily with Google Script within Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to be pulling in some data into a Google Sheet from an external source at 1am daily. The amount of products imported will vary.

I then wish to sort the data by price after the data has finished uploading, this will be around 1.05am.

I see it is possible to run functions for Google Sheets on a timed basis.

What script would I need to sort the data by price, so the cheapest items is row 2 after running a script every morning.

To do this manually in Google Sheets I would do - *Highlight rows 2 to *, Data, Sort Range, Sort by column I, A - Z*

How would this translate into a function? the timed function look easy enough to do as a trigger (although a set time doesn;t seem possible only an hour range)

Here is the shared sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hRW92xesCZzrTRU8DzrdJ_XtrQoJbbNhA3nVT452
apE/edit?usp=sharing

**SOLUTION - Thanks to Ed & Cooper**

First, freeze the first row manually. (Search for freeze) https://support.google.com/docs/answer/54813?hl=en

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Sorts the sheet by the column I - the ninth across - , in ascending order 
sheet.sort(9);
}
```

Comment: do credit the correct answer by marking it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Set this function to run one hour after you data is available:

```
function sortPrice() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XHOlmI6LA4jvnh1YXossBrbrnIOdyRmvO2warz1vl9s")
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("4cat").activate()
  var lr =s.getLastRow()
  var lc= s.getLastColumn()
  var rng=s.getRange(2, 1, lr, lc)//get range to sort
  var sort= rng.sort({column: 9, ascending: true}) //sort on column I
}
```

Comment: So exact timing not available in the project triggers? Alas, Could have done with the data sorting as fast as possible as the daily data feeds into an app. Will get the data imported a bit before 1am now then choose the 1am-2am trigger slot. Thanks

Comment: If your current trigger that downloads the data is a function, try calling this function at the end of the existing function. You can't set an exact time. I have a nightly trigger set for 10:00 pm. I runs at 10:22 every night. Why? I don't know. I do run a lot of functions from that one trigger.